# How to display a variable that keeps changing with flask and python?

Tags: python, for-loop, flask, jinja2, auto-update

I am experimenting a little with python and flask, how can I make a webpage that keeps updating itself?
Here I make a for-loop to keep x counting, I set it to index.html using jinja2 but it doesn't work, also when I try to access the website the browser keeps charging and then nothing happens just a white page and no request at all in the shell.

Flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import time


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    for x in range(0, 1000):
        time.sleep(1)
    return render_template("index.html", x=x)
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <h1> Title </h1>
    <tbody>
        {{ x }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually it works as it should: your page is not rendered until loop is passed. Loop takes 1000 seconds to pass. And even if your browser wont raise timeout error - you will get page displays 999 ( last x value from loop )

Comment: I suggest you to take a look into [Dash](https://dash.plot.ly/) framework. Written on top of Flask, Plotly.js, and React.js, Dash is ideal for building data visualization apps with highly custom user interfaces in pure Python. It's particularly suited for anyone who works with data in Python.

Comment: you should use `AJAX` in your template to send a request every 1 second.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  I didn't see it that way its true it won't rendered until the for loop its over, I'll going to look on dash, My idea is to show data to the user as it comes(on real time) hope dash suit me for that

Comment: Senaps! man that is just what i wanted to do, thanks for the hint mate!